# Windows 11: do not bug me with USB device notifications

Tags: windows, usb, windows-11

Windows 11 keeps bugging me about some unrecognized USB device (I have no USB devices attached other than mouse and keyboard - not even the front panel).

I have switched off everything I could find in settings that allows Windows to send me notifications or play a sound. The notification doesn't show up anymore, but the sound is still played every few seconds.

How can I forbid Windows 11 to play this sound? I think it's the USB device connected sound.

I had the same problem with Windows 10 before, but at least I could forbid Windows 10 to bug me with this annoying sound. My Windows 10 installation was a few years old already and probably a bit messed up anyway. My Windows 11 installation is brand new though. No upgrade from Windows 10, but a new installation. No weird stuff installed, just Steam and Epic. All drivers come from Windows update.

Is this a Windows bug? Or is my mainboard kinda toast? Apart from this annoying sound I have no issues with this computer.

EDIT:

Actually, I found a device in device manager, but I have no idea what it is:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I couldn't make the window bigger to show the hole text, but I could copy it:

```
Device USB\VID_0000&PID_0002\6&3505d85a&0&3 was configured.

Driver Name: usb.inf
Class Guid: {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}
Driver Date: 06/21/2006
Driver Version: 10.0.22621.4
Driver Provider: Microsoft
Driver Section: BADDEVICE.Dev.NT
Driver Rank: 0xFF0000
Matching Device Id: USB\DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR_FAILURE
Outranked Drivers: usb.inf:USB\DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR_FAILURE:00FF2000
Device Updated: false
Parent Device: USB\ROOT_HUB30\5&19706b00&0&0
```

I have no idea what device this is supposed to be. Can I block this somehow?

Comment: It is NOT a Windows 11 bug (nothing like that on 2 production and 1 Insider machine.  Run DISM / SFC and see if (hope) that corrects it. ...    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: It’s not a Windows bug. You will need to use Device Manager to identify the device

Comment: @John: I did what you suggested and for a time it seemed like that had helped; the frequency for the sound was significantly reduced. But now its back again.