# How to disable USB connect notification sound?

Tags: usb, windows-11, notifications, system-sounds

I've asked a [similar question](https://superuser.com/q/1770870/661137) before, but that one was too much focused on fixing the underlaying problem. I don't have high hopes that this is fixable, it might be some sort of spasm of my mainboard.

I really would like to get rid of the USB connect notification sound. I've gone through the settings and managed to get rid of the notification, but the sound is still played.

So, how can I actually disable this sound? If I could disable all notification sounds that would be a valid solution. I haven't found a setting like this though. But I don't want to disable sound itself; I still want to have sound in my video games :)

The sound in question is a ding-ding, a lower note followed by a higher note when connecting a USB device, and the reverse sound - the higher note followed by a lower note - when disconnecting the USB device.

If there is no way to disable this sound cleanly in settings, I wouldn't mind a more hack-ish solution to simply delete the sound file, if someone could point me to it. If deleting the file could lead to problems or Windows unsolicitedly 'fixes' itself, maybe I could replace the file with an empty file?

Comment: "I've gone through the settings" – Do you mean System Sounds, like [here](https://www.lifewire.com/change-system-sounds-in-windows-11-5193804)? (It's a shot in the dark, I haven't tinkered with Windows since Windows 7.)

Comment: Go through the Control Panel, Sounds, each one (that may be appropriate), turn the sound off and check.

Comment: Setting Windows Sounds to silent has always caused the USB connect/disconnect sound to go away. So, what have you actually done? Please tell us specifically what you have done.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: I followed your link and followed the instructions there and selected Sound Scheme: No sounds. That did the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: @music2myear: I guess I haven't gone through all the settings, just the notification settings. These offered some sound settings as well, but I couldn't find the relevant setting in the notifications area.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to just disable USB sounds, either:

- right click on the volume icon in tray and select `Sounds`
  or:
- go to `Settings` -> `Personalization` -> `Themes` -> `Sounds` -> `Sounds`

Then in `Program Events` disable:

- `Device Connect`
- `Device Disconnect`

sounds by selecting `{None}` for them in the dropdown. You don't have to disable everything as in selecting `no sounds` for `Sound scheme`. Then you can also save the new scheme as a separate entry in case you want to switch back to the original.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason Windows is repeatedly playing the device connect and device disconnect sound effects after I disconnected my iPhone. I haven't plugged it back in, and I'm still hearing the sound effects several minutes later.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. I'd recommend searching/asking a different question for that issue. Likely related to not using the "safe disconnect" functionality available in tray. But from what I've experienced personally, some things like explorer.exe can get buggy sometimes even when using that.